# Как отсортировать записи?

Tags: php, mysql

Я делаю сортировку по порядку сверху вниз. Если пустые ячейки, то они сортируются вверху и после них идут ячейки по алфавиту, которые заполнены. Как сделать чтобы в начале шли по алфавиту, а пустые ячейки были внизу?

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY $order ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY ISNULL($order) ASC, $order ASC
```

Comment: Странно, но у меня почему-то все также

Comment: убедитесь что в пустых ячейках действительно NULL а не ''

Comment: Там пустое поле

Comment: проверено - работает. ищите проблемы на вашей стороне

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Clients
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN $order IS NULL OR $order = '' THEN 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' ELSE 
$order END
```

Можно так при условии, что у вас `$order` Строковое. 
В общем, в условие `THEN` подставьте строку в зависимости от кодировки вашего поля
и в зависимости от содержимого.

Можете, конечно, какую-нибудь числовую функцию от строки ввести и по ней уже сортировать

```
CASE WHEN $order IS NULL OR $order = '' THEN <Большое число> ELSE <Функция от строки, однозначно определяющая порядок>
```

Либо можете сделать так:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders 
WHERE NOT $order IS NULL AND $order <> ''
ORDER BY $order
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Orders 
WHERE $order IS NULL OR $order = ''
```

Comment: Вот последний вариант такую ошибку выдает:
Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: пробовали с CASE?
Ошибку он и вправду даст, сортировка ведь)

Comment: c UNION ALL сработает 
если вы создадите две временные таблички
и запихаете в них первую часть данных потом вторую
а уж между ними 
UNION ALL